# wix - defining conditions according properties

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have to create a single MSI that supports multiple environments.
I mean that the IIS configuration is different between environments (different application pools , users etc.) so I want to prepare all the possible configurations in the MSI and decide which one to activate based on a property (the property is the environment value).
What is the way to create such "conditional" configurations that are dependent on a property value?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is completely based on your requirement. You can use [SetProperty](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_setproperty.htm) element (to set the Property value based on the condition) or Custom actions. (To run the custom action based on the property value or condition.)